# Oracle - select all where one of the columns satisfies predicate

Tags: oracle

I have a table with 30+ rows and i want to do a select * however i also want to make sure that no rows containing null values are returned for a certain column. How can i do this without having to list each of the column names in the select?

My current SQL looks like this;

```
select * 
  from table 
 where (select column 
          from table 
         where column is not null) is > 20
```

However this does not work as the nested select returns more than one value.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: ok so i can use the where clause and include the column name for something like this where column_name is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select * from table where column is not null
```

maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE column > 20
```

Is that sufficient?